# Android fragment, findViewById() returning null, but getView() returning correct view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I was learning android fragments. I made a separate layout for large screens. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Used in layout-large folder -->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment android:name="com.muktadir.news.HeadlinesFragment"
                  android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment android:name="com.muktadir.news.ArticleFragment"
                  android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
                  android:layout_weight="2"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the article_view layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:padding="@dimen/article_view_padding"
        android:textSize="@dimen/article_view_text_size"
        android:text="I should be here">

    </TextView>
```

Now I am calling `updateArticleView()` from `MainActivity` which is actually updating the `TextView` inflated by the `ArticleFragment`. I am getting `NULL` by this line:

```
 getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
```

But **`getView()` works fine and I can update the text**. I printed the view hierarchy and it has the element, but somehow `findViewById()` of the activity cannot return the object. Can you explain it?

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment{

final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
final static String TAG = "ArticleFragment";

int mCurrentPosition = -1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition); //can save negative!
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Bundle args = getArguments(); // this is to get the position of article for the first instantiation.
    if(args != null){
        updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
    } else if(mCurrentPosition != -1) {
        updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
    }
}

public  void updateArticleView(int selectedArticle){ // this is also called from mainactivity

    Activity myActivity = getActivity();
    Log.d(TAG, myActivity.toString());
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) myActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    //printViewHierarchy(view , "debug");

    Log.d(TAG, "article id " + String.valueOf(R.id.article));
    // TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);

    TextView article = (TextView) getView();
    Log.d(TAG, article.toString());
    article.setText(IpSum.Articles[selectedArticle]);
    mCurrentPosition = selectedArticle;

}

public static void printViewHierarchy(ViewGroup $vg, String $prefix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < $vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = $vg.getChildAt(i);
        String desc = $prefix + " | " + "[" + i + "/" + ($vg.getChildCount()-1) + "] "+ v.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + v.getId();
        Log.v("x", desc);
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            printViewHierarchy((ViewGroup)v, desc);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe that because the TextView is top level element in your layout its ID is overwritten with that of the fragment. If you look up R.id.article_fragment it should return the TextView. On some platforms, sometimes (not sure of precise conditions) the fragment is wrapped in NoSaveStateFrameLayout.

Comment: @EugenPechanec: If you print the view hierarchy of the activity, you will see that the element exists and when fragment returns the view, it's attached to the LinearLayout of the activity. And there is another fragment in the Layout of the activity. So, what's overwritten actually and where?

Comment: Btw, if I add fragments dynamically (without class names in activity layout), it does work.

Comment: The root (and only) element of yout fragment's layout is a TextView with @id/article. When you inflate the fragment you provided @id/headlines_fragment (or @id/article_fragment) which overwrites the fragment's root view's ID. You will find views with @id/headlines_fragment and @id/article_fragment, both TextViews.

Comment: When you add fragments dynamically, you provide a container's ID into which the fragments are inflated so nothing gets overwritten. Beware now you have de facto two TextViews with @id/article in the activity so anytime you invoke activity.findViewById you will always get the first one. fragment.getView().findViewById is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It returns you `null` because your layout does not contain `TextView` with `android:id="@+id/article"` attribute. It's part of fragment's `article_view.xml` layout.

So when you call `getView()` in fragment, you call for current fragment view. Also, binding should be done in `onCreateView` method:

```
private TextView article;

public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);

    article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this on your updateArticleView

```
 ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.article_view);

 TextView article = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article);
```

but I believe that you have to go with @Damian Kozlak 's suggestion.

Comment: I gave the solution already in the code [ TextView article = (TextView) getView() ]. When myActivity.findViewById(R.id.article_view) returns null, it doesn't matter whether you cast it to View or ViewGroup! I will investigate it more.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the scope of findViewById().The documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html says:

> onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

The findViewById() method is explained further at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)

> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
>
> **Returns**
> The view if found or null otherwise.

So the method is only able to get references to your LinearLayout and your 2 Fragments inflated using setContentView().
The view created by inflating article_view.xml inside your fragment is the root of your fragment so getView() is the appropiate method here

Comment: Sorry. It's not violating the documentation at all. 

Firstly, You can attach views to view hierarchy after onCreate and get them by findViewById of the activity viewGroup.

Secondly, In the case I wrote here, Fragment items are indeed in Layout which is indeed processed in onCreate of the Activity. 

Btw, the code was taken from Derek Banas Tutorial which should have worked back in 2013 when he did those and commentors didn't face the problem.

Comment: Ooh I thought that might be the problem, so have you found out what was causing the null view?

Comment: I will dig into that some day. Btw, both the ways work when I add fragment dynamically. I see the problem occurs when fragment class names are given in the activity layout! If you just add the fragments in onCreate of the activity without fragment names in the layout, the problem doesn't happen! It will take some time to debug this kind of things :( I expected some grand-master would just help me out.